# Find $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ such that all solutions of the equation are in the interval

Tags: real-analysis

Find $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ such that all solutions of the equation: $x^{2}-2\lambda x+\lambda^{2}-1=0$ are in the interval $<-2,4>$

My attempt:

$-2<\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}<4$

$-2<\frac{2\lambda\pm\sqrt{4\lambda^{2}-4(\lambda^{2}-1)}}{2}<4$

$-4<2\lambda\pm 2<8$

$1)$ $-4<2\lambda+2<8$

$-6<2\lambda<6$

$-3<\lambda<3$

$\Rightarrow \lambda\in <-3,3>$

$2)$ $-4<2\lambda-2<8$

$-2<2\lambda<10$

$-1<\lambda<5$

$\Rightarrow \lambda \in <-1, 5>$

From $1)$ and $2)$ I got that $\lambda\in <-3,5>$, but when take for instance $\lambda=-2$ I get $x_1=-3$ and $x_2=-1$. $-3$ is obviously not in $<2,4>$ so I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Intersection of $<-3,3>$ and $<-1,5>$ is not $<-3,5>$. You have confused it with union.

Comment: I thought it should be union?

Comment: No, union is where one root is in the interval  - "or" connection of both cases. For the "and" connection, you need the intersection.

Comment: It is an intersection because you want that $\lambda$ belongs to both intervals at the same time, i.e. $\lambda$ is a solution if it hold for both roots of $x$.